# how to add ssl to an http server on boost and asio

Tags: c++, http, ssl

I copied the http server code from the official [Boost HTTP Server 3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_3) example and changed it a little to suit my needs, mainly in the request_handler and request_parser files, that is, I did not change the request acceptance code in any way. After my server started accepting and processing POST requests, I needed to transfer it from http to https, I found an [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.cpp) of a server with ssl on the same page as http.

```
class session {
public:
    session(boost::asio::io_context &io_context,
            boost::asio::ssl::context &context)
            : socket_(io_context, context) {
    }

    ssl_socket::lowest_layer_type &socket() {
        return socket_.lowest_layer();
    }

    void start() {
        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
                                boost::bind(&session::handle_handshake, this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code &error) {
        if (!error) {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                                    boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        } else {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code &error,
                     size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!error) {
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                                     boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
                                     boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        } else {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code &error) {
        if (!error) {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                                    boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        } else {
            delete this;
        }
    }

private:
    ssl_socket socket_;
    enum {
        max_length = 1024
    };
    char data_[max_length];
};

class server {
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context &io_context, unsigned short port)
            : io_context_(io_context),
              acceptor_(io_context,
                        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
              context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23) {
        context_.set_options(
                boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
                | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
                | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
        context_.set_password_callback(boost::bind(&server::get_password, this));
        context_.use_certificate_chain_file("server.pem");
        context_.use_private_key_file("server.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
        context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

        start_accept();
    }

    std::string get_password() const {
        return "test";
    }

    void start_accept() {
        session *new_session = new session(io_context_, context_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                               boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_accept(session *new_session,
                       const boost::system::error_code &error) {
        if (!error) {
            new_session->start();
        } else {
            delete new_session;
        }

        start_accept();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_context &io_context_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::ssl::context context_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;

        using namespace std; // For atoi.
        server s(io_context, atoi(argv[1]));

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But that code takes up only one file and I can't find how to distribute it across my server so that it can accept https requests, since the server structure with Boost HTTP Server 3 is much larger.

Here is the code from my server files that contain the same functions.
connection.cpp:

```cpp
#include "../headers/connection.h"
#include <vector>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "../headers/request_handler.h"

namespace http::server3 {

    connection::connection(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, request_handler &handler) : strand_(io_service),
                                                                                            socket_(io_service),
                                                                                            request_handler_(handler) {}

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &connection::socket() {
        return socket_;
    }

    void connection::start() {
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), strand_.wrap(
                boost::bind(&connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    }

    void connection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code &e, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!e) {
            boost::tribool result;
            boost::tie(result, boost::tuples::ignore) = request_parser_.parse(
                    request_, buffer_.data(), buffer_.data() + bytes_transferred);

            if (result) {
                request_handler_.handle_request(request_, reply_);
                boost::asio::async_write(socket_, reply_.to_buffers(),
                                         strand_.wrap(
                                                 boost::bind(&connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                                                             boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
            } else if (!result) {
                reply_ = reply::stock_reply(reply::bad_request);
                boost::asio::async_write(socket_, reply_.to_buffers(),
                                         strand_.wrap(
                                                 boost::bind(&connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                                                             boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
            } else {
                socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
                                        strand_.wrap(
                                                boost::bind(&connection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
            }
        }

        // If an error occurs then no new asynchronous operations are started. This
        // means that all shared_ptr references to the connection object will
        // disappear and the object will be destroyed automatically after this
        // handler returns. The connection class's destructor closes the socket.
    }

    void connection::handle_write(const boost::system::error_code &e) {
        if (!e) {
            // Initiate graceful connection closure.
            boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
            socket_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored_ec);
        }

        // No new asynchronous operations are started. This means that all shared_ptr
        // references to the connection object will disappear and the object will be
        // destroyed automatically after this handler returns. The connection class's
        // destructor closes the socket.
    }

} // namespace http
```

server.cpp:

```cpp
#include "../headers/server.h"
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace http::server3 {
    server::server(const std::string &address, const std::string &port, std::size_t thread_pool_size)
            : thread_pool_size_(thread_pool_size), acceptor_(io_service_),
              new_connection_(new connection(io_service_, request_handler_)) {
        // Open the acceptor with the option to reuse the address (i.e. SO_REUSEADDR).
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
        acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor_.listen();
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection_->socket(),
                               boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void server::run() {
        // Create a pool of threads to run all of the io_services.
        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > threads;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size_; ++i) {
            boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread(
                    new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_)));
            threads.push_back(thread);
        }

        // Wait for all threads in the pool to exit.
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i) threads[i]->join();
    }

    void server::stop() {
        io_service_.stop();
    }

    void server::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code &e) {
        if (!e) {
            new_connection_->start();
            new_connection_.reset(new connection(io_service_, request_handler_));
            acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection_->socket(),
                                   boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }
} // namespace http
```

and main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include "headers/server.h"

#if defined(_WIN32)

boost::function0<void> console_ctrl_function;

BOOL WINAPI console_ctrl_handler(DWORD ctrl_type) {
    switch (ctrl_type) {
        case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
            console_ctrl_function();
            return TRUE;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        // Initialise server.
        std::size_t num_threads = boost::lexical_cast<std::size_t>("10");
        http::server3::server s("10.200.0.197", "80", num_threads);

        // Set console control handler to allow server to be stopped.
        console_ctrl_function = boost::bind(&http::server3::server::stop, &s);
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(console_ctrl_handler, TRUE);

        // Run the server until stopped.
        s.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

#endif // defined(_WIN32)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example as it is not possible to help you without any code samples.

Comment: @Azrael3000, added